# ./ungrib.exe: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpng12.so.0: version `PNG12_0' not found (required by ./ungrib.exe)

Tags: 14.04, command-line, bash, permissions

Recently I installed WRFV version 4 and now am trying to `ungrib.exe` but it shows:

```
./ungrib.exe: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpng12.so.0: version `PNG12_0' not found (required by ./ungrib.exe)
```

giving ldd ungrib.exe it shows:

```
./ungrib.exe: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpng12.so.0: version `PNG12_0' not found (required by ./ungrib.exe)
    linux-vdso.so.1 (0x00007ffd599fc000)
    libpng12.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpng12.so.0 (0x00007f0907e20000)
    libgfortran.so.4 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgfortran.so.4 (0x00007f0907a41000)
    libm.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6 (0x00007f09076a3000)
    libgcc_s.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1 (0x00007f090748b000)
    libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007f090709a000)
    libz.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libz.so.1 (0x00007f0906e7d000)
    libquadmath.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libquadmath.so.0 (0x00007f0906c3d000)
    /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007f0908333000)
```

and this is my `bashrc` path:

```
export LDFLAGS=-L$DIR/grib2/lib
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$DIR/libpng-1.2.50
export CPPFLAGS=-I$DIR/grib2/include
export PATH=$DIR/netcdf/bin:$PATH
export NETCDF=$DIR/netcdf
export JASPERLIB=$DIR/grib2/lib
export JASPERINC=$DIR/grib2/include
export NCARG_ROOT=$DIR/ncl
export PATH=$NCARG_ROOT/bin:$PATH
export DISPLAY=:0.0
```

please help

Comment: I revised the instructions because it won't install system wide. You can create an alias for `wgrib` or you can just execute the full path `~/$HOME/WGRIB/wgrib` or `~/WGRIB/wgrib` (same thing).

Comment: I also edited the path for `wgrib2` as I forgot that there was a subdirectory for `wgrib2` so to execute: `~/grib2/wgrib2/wgrib2`

Answer (score 1):

**I think it might be easier to use [wgrib](https://www.cpc.ncep.noaa.gov/products/wesley/wgrib.html) instead as it compiles on linux instead of an exe file.**

[Click here for more info.](https://www.cpc.ncep.noaa.gov/products/wesley/wgrib.html)

To download and compile, run the following commands:

```
cd
mkdir WGRIB; cd WGRIB
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install build-essential
wget ftp://ftp.cpc.ncep.noaa.gov/wd51we/wgrib/wgrib.tar
tar xvf wgrib.tar
make
```

Now, you can run `wgrib`:

```
./wgrib
```

To run the file from your terminal in any directory, execute the following command:

```
~/WGRIB/wgrib
```

You can also add this as an alias to your `~/.bashrc` file by adding the following line to your `~/.bashrc` file:

```
alias wgrib="$HOME/WGRIB/wgrib"
```

and then run the following command to apply the changes:

```
. ~/.bashrc
```

Now you should be able to run `wgrib` by executing the following command:

```
wgrib
```

---

**Additionally, you can also use [wgrib2](https://www.cpc.ncep.noaa.gov/products/wesley/wgrib2/) instead**

[Click here for more information.](https://www.cpc.ncep.noaa.gov/products/wesley/wgrib2/)

```
cd
wget ftp://ftp.cpc.ncep.noaa.gov/wd51we/wgrib2/wgrib2.tgz
tar xvf wgrib2.tgz
cd grib2
export CC=gcc
make
cd wgrib2
./wgrib2
```

This one doesn't want to install system wide for some reason but the full-path to the executable is:

```
~/grib2/wgrib2/wgrib2
```

or

```
$HOME/grib2/wgrib2/wgrib2
```

Comment: Thanks mchid for your quick reply. i downloaded WGRIB.tar and complied it in that it shows an error after running "sudo make install" i.e "make: *** No rule to make target 'install'.  Stop.

Comment: @sainani Oh, I see. Just run `wgrib` from the local directory instead if it won't install. So you can run it by executing: `~/WGRIB/wgrib`

Comment: @sainani Also, I have revised the instructions to execute the `wgrib2` command and it is: `~/grib2/wgrib2/wgrib2`

Comment: @sainani If this is an acceptable answer, please click the check mark icon to the left to mark this question as solved. Otherwise, you can also upvote this question by clicking the up arrow icon to the left to give me points. Thanks!